# jQuery code works in console but not in site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following jQuery code in a wordpress site.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
   if (event.target !== this)
   return;
   jQuery(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
   jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass("show");
  });
 });
});
```

The class being toggled sets the ".sub-menu" element to be displayed from "none" to "block".

It works fine in the console in chrome dev tools, but not in the page, and it is placed after the DOM element is created.

If i change the code to the following, A alert executes, so the jQuery code executes no problem.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert("working");
 });
```

Any suggestions as to why this is?

**EDIT:**

The solution was

```
jQuery(".menu-item").click(function(event){
```

instead of

```
jQuery(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: What does `console.log(jQuery(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").length)` return? If it is zero something else is the problem

Comment: share html also

Comment: no errors in the console, and console.log(jQuery(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").length) returns 6

Comment: Share your code (html,js,css) here : https://jsfiddle.net/ with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead.

```
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").on('click',function(event){
           if (event.target !== this)
               return;
           $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
               $(this).parent().toggleClass("show");
           });
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```